# Community Wiki And Sidebar

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if a post like [Where can I find some Solidity / Smart Contract source code examples?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/where-can-i-find-some-solidity-smart-contract-source-code-examples) and other reference materials can be made into community wiki pages.

And can these be listed in the sidebar, instead of the "Hot Network Questions" which is not useful for users in this Ethereum SE?

Comment: By the way, lists and requests for resources are in most cases off topic on stack exchange sites.

Comment: Noted. Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For converting the answer to a community wiki, edit it and in the lower right, there's a checkbox for community wiki.

I don't know about the sidebar.

A moderator can also convert questions to a community wiki, which I've done for [Where can I find some Solidity / Smart Contract source code examples?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/where-can-i-find-some-solidity-smart-contract-source-code-examples)

Comment: When I edit the post, it does not have the community wiki checkbox. I do see the community wiki checkbox when I ask a new question. I'll probably need a moderator to perform this change as I don't have the permissions.

Comment: Thank. I was trying to set the Question to community wiki mode but it's the Answer that can be set to community wiki mode.

Comment: You're right moderator can change a question to community wiki; I updated the answer.  Do you want your theDAO questions with wiki answers, to also become a community wiki?  This will encourage improvement of a single wiki answer, instead of multiple wikis.

Comment: I'm happy with your moderator's judgement to change my questions and answers into community wikis as you see fit. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I try to be very careful with it, and if I ever mess up, please let me know and no harm intended.

Comment: No worries. You moderators are doing a good job keeping things together / coherent.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone with 10 reputation can [create community wiki posts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki). Simply use the checkbox below and confirm that you understand this is not reversible:

[image: community wiki check box]

The hot network questions are generated automatically by the stack exchange network and we have no influence on this.

I've seen a question from our site to show up on that list once, it's a cool feature. We need more hot questions!