# Beginner References / Resources

Tags: discussion

I would like to see something like an "Introduction to", "Beginner's Guide" or something similar to make it easier for a beginner to get access the to relevant resources. The answers should be community wiki style so a easily readable list can be built up.

Some relevant questions I have found so far that I would like to link into the series are:

1. [Where can I learn how to develop DApps using the solidity programming language?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/where-can-i-learn-how-to-develop-dapps-using-the-solidity-programming-language)
2. [Where can I find some Solidity / Smart Contract source code examples?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/where-can-i-find-some-solidity-smart-contract-source-code-examples)
3. [Is there a list of DAPPS that are already useable?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-there-a-list-of-dapps-that-are-already-useable)

**My Questions**

1. Should this kind of thing be done? Or is this NOT how *.stackexchange.com run as SEs have their algorithms for determining the priority of posts?
2. Should the questions like the ones above be edited to link them together (as done in the second question above)? I've linked the questions 1. and 3. above in 2.
3. Should a tag like "beginners", "starters" or something like that be used to link these sort of questions together?
4. How can these questions be featured so a visitor to this website is able to easily access these resources? Sticky, sidebar, featured?

---

Other related questions:

- [Let's create tag excerpts and wiki entries!](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/lets-create-tag-excerpts-and-wiki-entries)
- [How many meta questions should have a 'featured' tag?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188/how-many-meta-questions-should-have-a-featured-tag)
- [Community Wiki And Sidebar](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/community-wiki-and-sidebar)
- [Do we eventually ruthlessly edit questions (and answers)?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169/do-we-eventually-ruthlessly-edit-questions-and-answers?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, please don't :-)

Answering your questions one by one:

1. No, this is not how stack exchange sites work. Usually 90% of traffic comes from search engines from users which have a very *specialized* problem. They are (in most cases) not really looking for canonical questions or wiki overviews.
2. Don't link them unless there is a good reason or if that post is not yours.
3. Please don't create meta tags. If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question, it's probably a meta-tag. If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it's probably a meta-tag.
4. Hot questions will automatically features on the network and on the front pages. Threads which list other threads, are usually not hot.

So, TL;DR please don't.

Comment: OK. Will clean up now.

Comment: Don't remove existing content, there is certainly no need for. But please, refrain from creating more of such posts.

Comment: I've cleaned up the recent questions & I'll ask meta before doing any more of this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Q1 and Q4.  There's ethdocs.org which may help.

With Q2, linking always seems helpful, with generally little disadvantage.

With Q3, we could discuss
[Should we delete meta-tags?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243/should-we-delete-meta-tags?s=1|2.0692)

Comment: Regarding Q1, sites like ethdocs.org do provide a more complete reference. However some users do experience issues when they first start using the Ethereum software / system, and linking the information across the different reference materials site does take quite a bit of effort if they do encounter any out-of-the-ordinary problems. I'm still trying to work out what ESE's place is.